# Cross domain AJAX requests are not being blocked: is this a security vulnerability?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, cross-domain

I spent the last 3 days studying how to make a cross domain request using XMLHttpRequest. The best alternative is indeed with JSONP which I am already using.

But I still have a question that I could not find answer nowhere. I read hundreds of posts (including SOs) and nobody has a good liable answer (with nice reference). Hope someone here can help.

Said that, I read in many websites that due to security reasons I cannot make an Ajax request from domain example.com to yyy.com and get the data I want. It's very clear and I have no question about that. BUT the problem is when I run the code below in my localhost (so my domain is "localhost" and I should not me able to request any data from another domain).

```
xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("GET","http://domain.com.br?parameter",true);
xhReq.send(null);
```

When I inspect the Firebug Net Tab I realize that the request was not blocked! It was clearly requested. I could not believe. So I created a file in the domain.com.br/log.php where I could log any request that hit my domain. Surprisingly all the requests I was firing localhost were hitting my domain.com.br. When I tried to fetch the response I really could not get it due the same origin policy of my Chrome and FIrebug browser. But I was reallyl surprised that the request really hit the webserver despite I could no manipulate the responde.

More surprisingly is that if domain.com.br/log.php generates a huge responde with like 1MB my firebug showed me that the browser does download ALL th 1MB from the webserver, and at the end it shows a message "Access denied" as expected. So why download all the file if the same origin policy forbids that data to be read.

Finally, I makes me amazed, is that all the websites and specifications I read says very CLEAR that the request is blocked using Ajax when the target domain does not match the source domain. But clearly, with my experiment, the requests are being completed, despite I cannot have access to the response data.

What makes me upset is that it could be open a BIG security hole, in which a website with thousands of views everyday could run this 3 line code and cause a HUGE Ddos attack in an unfriendly website just making the users request a page in another website in small intervals since the browser will not block the request.

I tested this script in IE 7, 8 and 9 and Chrome latest and Firefox latest and the behaviour is the same: the request is done and the browser downloads all the response while not making it avaiblable to do SOP.

Hope someone can explain me why the specs are so wrong about it or what I am understanding wrong!

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy): Under the same-origin policy, cross-site sending of information is also dangerous since it enables attacks such as cross-site request forgery (CSRF) and clickjacking. The same-origin policy cannot address these security vulnerabilities in the same way it does those around receiving of information since prohibiting cross-site sending of information would prohibit cross-site hyperlinks. **Without "allow sending," there would be no "web" at all because each origin would be allowed to link only to itself.**

Comment: @Andreas thanks for helping but I think I may not be clear. I undertand that the browser should allow request to external domains like you embed an image, an script, a css sheet... But allowing it with Ajax is a huge threat since a Dos attack can be performed against any webserver. The specs always say that a request made to an external domain using ajax should always be blocked. Which is wrongs cause as I proved, the request is not being blocked, only the response.

Comment: Compare the behavior with a hidden iframe: if the content if from another domain then it cannot be accessed cross-domain in JavaScript, but the iframe content will be "fully downloaded". While I'm not sure about the specifics of XHR, it seems like this download-then-block *is no more of a problem* than existing methods of initiating transfer of restricted data.

Comment: From the one and only spec on w3.org [XmlHttpRequest.send()](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send%28%29-method): Step 10: `if <same origin> then ... else <Make a cross-origin request, ...>` No word about stopping the request to be send

Answer (score 5):

The request *can* be made, and the server may generate a response, regardless of CORS. However, the *response* may be hidden. balpha [wrote about this in his blog](http://balpha.de/2013/02/plain-text-considered-harmful-a-cross-domain-exploit/) recently:

> Note that the same origin policy doesn't necessarily prevent the request per se – it just prevents the response from being accessible. A malicious site can e.g. just redirect your browser, or submit a form, or include an image or an iframe – in all those cases a request is made to your site; the evil site just doesn't see the response.

To some extent, the browser *has* to make a request to the server to see if it servers an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header. Remember that CORS is completely implemented by the browser. Someone could just write a console application to make a request to your server, so you shouldn't rely on CORS to make sure requests are only coming from your own site.

Comment: Thanks for helping. The link you provided helped but not too much. The problem is that everywhere I read they say the browser show not even allow the request using Ajax. I know that if I put and <img> with external src it will not only hit the exteral resource but download it and show the response presenting like an image. But the specs are really clear that the request should not be completed. It's a security threat cause I could harm any website using this 3 line code, just like a Dos attack.

Comment: @Samul but you could implement those 3 lines of code in a plain C console (albeit with more than 3 lines) application that has absolutely no concept of CORS. Having CORS block the request doesn't gain any additional security.

Comment: I agree with you. The CORS does not prevent the Dos attack cause I can append a GET parameter to the URL and it will always look different, dispite the CORS says the browser should not request that website again. Changing the url (even appending a random parameter) will always make the browser request the external resource, despite ANY header sent by the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same effect (like a dos attack you said) with a simple image file, it does not necessarily need to be XHR. Link an image file from a different website, put millions of it in your page, display it to your users and boom.

Comment: You are very right! But it's very well known that it's possible to embed external images, script, css sheets in a page... But it was also very clear that Ajax requests should always be blocked when requesting an external resource. As I proved, only the response is being blocked. And there a potential threat in this: using Ajax I can simulate a POST do any webserver login and overload their database which I could not do with images.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the policy requires that the request should be denied or the access. They're different. However you can still simulate any post to any website without XHR. Create a form, set the action to the login page of the target website. Submit it on page load! Here you have a no XHR post request.